# Backbone model inherits collections url

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, thorax.js

I have a Backbone collection(Actually a Thorax collection) where I have a function file following to do a fetch.

```
    fetchAllOfferedSchoolQualifications : function () {
        this.fetch({
            url : this.urlRoot(),
            type : 'GET'
        });
    },
```

Lets say this fetch goes to url 'localhost:80/myapp/qalifications

after fetch done. I get a model from that fetched collection, change some attribute and to a `model.save()`. Model does a `PUT` call. But the question is is uses the same url it inherit from the collection. The logic to generate url of backbone is as follows.

```
url: function() {
  var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

this is where it create the correct url. In backbone Sync it checks for the url as follows

```
// Ensure that we have a URL.
if (!options.url) {
  params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
}
```

Since the model has the collections fetched url it is using that url as it is for the PUT. Event thought I nuke the url of the model like follows.

```
model.url = undefined;
```

since the url is not available backbone checks whether there is a function `url` in the model. If not it throws a error.

So,

1. Model inherits collections url. Is this correct
2. If so backbone doesn't follow RESTFUL url pattern ``qualifications[id]

Can anyone explain this situation please?

Comment: What is exactly your question? Backbone takes rootUrl and appends `/:id` to it if the model has an id.

Comment: Looks like if model already have a url property, it use that as it is.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and say what exactly you're trying to accomplish? Right now, you're talking about how you want to accomplish something, and your problems with that method; perhaps if we knew what you were trying to accomplish, we could offer a different suggestion.